# What government office can help me recover documents lost by the IRS?

Tags: united-states, irs, itin

In April 2016 I sent originals of several documents (including my newborn's vaccination card) to the IRS when applying for an [ITIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_Taxpayer_Identification_Number).  The IRS claims to have sent them back to me, but they have not arrived (as of September) and the IRS cannot prove they sent them.  I have not been able to resolve the issue through their customer service phone line, form 14692, or my local [TAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_the_Taxpayer_Advocate).

Who can I contact for help recovering my documents?  Would my congressman be able to assist?

Comment: Why would the irs need your kids vaccine card?

Comment: @Andy , that's a good question, but for the IRS. They want all kind of stuff before they believe you that you are a real person and give you an ITIN.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do. There is no government office designed for this, and your congressman isn't going to go rifle through IRS files.

The first thing you should do is verify the IRS has the correct mailing address. If the IRS has the correct mailing address, you could try submitting a missing mail inquiry with the United States Postal Service. Go to the following website to submit an inquiry: https://www.usps.com/help/missing-mail.htm

Given the amount of time, it's very likely you won't see the originals again. In that case, you'll need to look at having them replaced. The only document you specifically mentioned is immunization records. For those, I suggest contacting your child's doctor and requesting duplicate records. If you need help obtaining duplicates of any other documents, you can submit another question.